# BANG! Where do cards played in phase 2 go when "Abandoned Mine" is in effect

Tags: expansions, bang

In the **Fistful of Cards** expansion pack for the card game BANG!, the `Abandoned Mine` card states in both languages used on the card:

> Nella propria fase 1, il giocatore pesca dagli scarti (se finiscono, pesca dal mazzo). Nella propria fase 3, scarta a faccia in giù sul mazzo.

---

> During his phase 1, each player draws from the discards (if they run out, from the deck). In his phase 3, he discards face down on the deck.

Unfortunately, it never says what to do with the cards played in phase 2.

***Argument 1***

Some would argue that for the whole round, the discard pile becomes the draw pile and the original draw pile becomes the discard pile. So for example, during your phase 2, when you play a `Bang!` card, it would go face down on the original draw pile.

***Argument 2***

However, this card is very specific about stating which "phase" things happen in. Therefore, the other argument (and the one that it sounds like the card seems to say) is that: ONLY during phase 1, and ONLY during phase 3 the draw pile and discard pile are swapped. For example: when playing a `Bang!` card in phase 2, it would go to the original discard pile (face-up stack). This can get weird at times, because when playing `Indians`, the card says that all other players need to *discard* a `Bang!` card in order to avoid being hit. Since they are "discarding", would those cards go to the face-down pile?

**References**

Phases are talked about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!#Gameplay

And the Fistful of cards expansion is talked about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!#A_Fistful_Of_Cards
(When speaking about the Abandoned Mine, it's language does not use what is stated on the card.)

So, where are cards played in phase 2 actually placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I play with the French version of the game which is very clear and could be translated as follow:

> During phase 1 every player picks his card from the discard pile if it is possible. If so, **every card** discarded **during his round** will be put face-down on the draw pile

Translation from the original French card:

> Durant sa phase 1, si c'est possible, chaque joueur pioche ses cartes dans la défausse. Si c'est le cas, **toutes les cartes** défaussées **pendant son tour** seront posées face cachée sur le paquet

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer is a little more complicated and so doesn't match either of the arguments. While the original card's wording (Italian/English) doesn't match the effect, it doesn't affect **played** cards (like the `Bang!` you mentioned), nor does it affect other players outside of their turn (so `Bang!` cards discarded for `Indians` are discarded as normal).

This is clarified in their [official FAQ on the expansion](http://www.emilianosciarra.net/en/bang/expansions-bang/a-fistful-of-cards/faq):

> **Q4. Where I have to place my played cards while Abandoned Mine is in play, especially when I play Wells Fargo, General Store or Stagecoach?**
>
> A. There is a difference between "discarded" and "played" cards: Stagecoach, General Store and Wells Fargo are "played", while cards exceeding hand size limit at the end of the turn or by means of a Duel are "discarded". So, discarded cards goes on the draw deck, while played cards go on the discard deck. Draw the cards after Stagecoach and Wells Fargo always from the draw deck. Note that this applies to current player only: all other players draw and discard normally.

For clarification, here's how it works with certain cards. In all cases, the played card will go to the discard pile:

- **Cat Balou**: Unless you play it on yourself, the target will discard it normally.
- **Duel**: The `Bang!` cards *you* discard will be put on the deck, but those discarded by your opponent will go to the discard pile.
- **Indians**: All `Bang!` cards discarded by opponents will go to the discard pile.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of the card, and from the wikipedia link which states

> players draw from the discard pile and discard on the top of the deck.

is that when you play a card during phase 2 or if you make anyone discard cards (ex. Cat Balou) then it would go on top of the deck. My card (similar to VGO's translation but from Italian) has confirmed my understanding of this card.